# Hibernate - Manipulating collection post load

Tags: java, hibernate, events, collections, event-listener

We are trying to filter\manipulate Persistent Collection based upon the objects it contains (filter out specific entries).

Since this manipulation will be performed on a large number of different objects containing different collections it must be as generic as possible.
Filtering on HQL\SQL level is not an option since it will be impossible to maintain. This means it must be performed after the collection was loaded and initialized.
We are currently using many of the Hibernate Events to handle single objects,
so we tried listening on the `InitializeCollectionEvent`.
But as it turns out, most of our collections are initialized using HQL Fetch so this event won't be raised for them.

Is there any other Hibernate Event that we can use?

Any other place where the Collections are processed after they are loaded?

We are using Hibernate 4.1.7 .

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not a good idea to filter collection on server side, when the collection was loaded. If you do that it means smth goes wrong, rethink you db model or entity structure. One of the best way to filter collection - use HQL. Or you can either use 
@Where or @Loader, @Filter.

Comment: In a perfect world i would agree with you, but in this case changing the model\database is not an option since this is a massive and complex production system and the impact will be too big and risky.
As I mentioned above, Filtering is possible via HQL and also Hibernate annotation as you suggested but it will be very hard to maintain later on.
Ideally the manipulation should be performed within the loading phase, using an event or Loader class.

Comment: OK, Did you try @PostLoad ??? I am not sure, but you can try. And I suggest to try it in org.hibernate.Interceptor, just create your own implementation, it's easy to google, that Interceptor is really powerful class.

Comment: Interceptors could handle collection, but they won't be initialized.